# Selected row flickers when scrolling

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have bounded `DataGridView` with 5000 rows of data in Form where `dgv "fill"` forms area.
When I scroll it with keyboard up or down selected row flickers much on solid computer.
Is here a way to get rid of that flickering?

Here is how my `DataGridView` is setup:

```
    With DataGridView1
        .AllowUserToAddRows = False
        .AllowDrop = False
        .AllowUserToOrderColumns = False
        .AllowUserToResizeRows = False
        .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = fnt1
        .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
        .ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
        .MultiSelect = False
        .ReadOnly = True
        .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
        .GridColor = Color.FromArgb(240, 240, 240)
        .DefaultCellStyle.Font = fnt1
        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
     End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the flickering by implementing double buffering for that form

```
me.SetStyle(
ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint OR _
ControlStyles.UserPaint OR _
ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer,true)
```

This should work

Comment: Double-Buffering a form does not automatically double-buffer the child controls.

Comment: Hi Selim. As Lars say's this don't helps on my datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://bitmatic.com/c/fixing-a-slow-scrolling-datagridview) then

i really hope it helps

Comment: I allready uses this            .GetType.InvokeMember"DoubleBuffered", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or _ Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or _
                                  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, _
                                  Nothing, DataGridView1, New Object() {True}), but still have flickering.